# Determine location of npm package (like `gem which`)

Tags: javascript, rubygems, npm

Given a package name, how do I ask npm for its location?

Phrased another way, what I'm asking for is the npm equivalent to the `gem which` command:

```
$ gem which rack
$ /absolute/path/to/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack.rb
```

---

**EDIT**: People have suggested `npm ls [--long]`, but that doesn't give me local paths of my project's installed packages.

```
$ npm ls --long

node-project@0.0.1
│ /Users/pje/node-project
│ 
└── underscore@1.4.2
    JavaScript's functional programming helper library.
    git://github.com/documentcloud/underscore.git
    http://underscorejs.org

$ npm --version
1.1.65
```

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for, but you can get this information from `npm ll`. It'll print out a tree of all your installed packages and their locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm list <pkg> --parseable` will return only the `realPath` attribute of `pkg`. For example:

```
$ npm list underscore --parseable
/absolute/path/to/node-project/node_modules/underscore
```

Via the helpful [npm list documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/list.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't one, but you can `grep` through `npm ll` easily enough.

Comment: `npm ls` prints an ascii-art-ified representation of a tree structure—not what I'd call "easy enough" for `grep`

Comment: @pje Sorry, use `ll` which automatically turns on details including the full path. It's one line after the packagename@version

Comment: for me, `npm ll` prints three lines for each package: 1) `name@version` 2) tagline 3) package url. How are you seeing the location of the package on your machine? Is there a flag?

Comment: @pje As far as I know, `npm ll` is the same as `npm ls -long` which should list all the details NPM has. For me it shows name@version, full path, tagline, and package URL. You might try `npm ls -long` and see if it gives you anything different on your platform. I'm on Windows, but it shouldn't make a difference. What version of npm are you on?

Comment: looks like the [parseable](https://npmjs.org/doc/list.html#parseable) flag to `npm list` does this.